# Difference between Windows select and Unix select for nonblocking sockets

Tags: c++, linux, windows, macos, sockets

I try to get some C++ code from Windows platform to Mac OSX/Linux. The Windows implementation uses sockets and the select statement. Under Windows the fd_set given to select is defined as followed:

```
typedef struct fd_set {
        u_int fd_count;               /* how many are SET? */
        SOCKET  fd_array[FD_SETSIZE];   /* an array of SOCKETs */
} fd_set;
```

which is pretty bad, because FD_SETSIZE is small and I had to build a more dynamic approach which gives some trouble on 64bit Windows. Resolving all these problems on Windows, I run into problems on unix/linux/OSX because the fd_set looks there totally different.

Now the question. Is there a socket count limitation like in windows? What is a good solution work under Linux and Windows. If there is a limitation in socket count, what is the best workaround?

Comment: Windows has alternative API for waiting for socket events - `WSAAsyncSelect` and `WSAEventSelect`. AFAIK, neither is portable.

Comment: That's right I know the WSA Api. But I already got the whole communication part running, except the the single select statement. I don't want to rewrite the code if there is a way to get the select running proper.

Comment: FD_SETSIZE is normally at least 1024 on *nixes, vs 64 on Windows. There's no workaround, you'll have to switch to a different approach, such as using poll() or the [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/performance/reference/gcd_libdispatch_ref/Reference/reference.html) if 1024 is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know both OSs allow changing the size of the structure by #defining FD_SETSIZE before including the #include files (winsock.h for Windows). This means there is no real socket count limitation in Windows if you simply make the structure larger (the Windows documenation explicitly tells this). The FD_SET() etc. functions use the FD_SETSIZE macro (they are "inline" functions or even only macros).

In Linux you'll have the same problem. However under Linux the fd_set structure does not contain a count but only a bit field (!) of file descriptors (so if the first bytes on a little endian machine are 0x81,0x01 then file descriptors 0, 7 and 8 are in the set of file descriptors).

The first argument of the "select()" system call must be the length of the bitfield. Under Windows the first argument of "select()" should be 0.

As you see there are MANY differences between Windows and Linux so you may need to write a system-independent wrapper function (as for "closesocket()"/"close()"):

Under Linux you check the highest file descriptor number. Then you calculate: bitmap_size=(highest_number+64)&~63. You allocate bitmap_size/8 bytes and set the corresponding bits.

Under Windows you allocate a fd_set structure but with more fd_array entries.